# Java 11 and javafx usage? , error java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.controls not found . Even thought they exist

Tags: java, javafx

---

I am using :

java 11

maven

netbeans 11.3

and javaFX 11 LTS

stock example project for javaFX and java 11

Windows 10 latest update

---

I am trying to use java 11 and javaFX together (i am new to java 11) and followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cYDH1oKJPSc) but i keep getting the error that the **module javafx.controls doesnt exist** even though it exists in the path that is specified in the PATH_TO_FX variable. All the properties of the project are set as in the tutorial.

---

Here are the VM options for the project :

```
--module-path %PATH_TO_FX%


--add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml
```

---

Variable PATH_TO_FX has a valiue of `C:\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib` that is the filepath to the lib's of javafx

It was added in the enviroment variables editor

---

Here is the exeption in its entierty if anyone needs it for some reason:

```
error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.controls not found
Command execution failed.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine(ExecMojo.java:764)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine(ExecMojo.java:711)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute(ExecMojo.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
```

---

Comment: What is the value of `%PATH_TO_FX%`? Can you [edit] your question and post the value? Or do I have to watch the entire seven minute video to discover it? When dealing with paths, it is important to indicate your platform because path syntax differs depending on the platform. So [edit] your question and post the platform you are on.

Comment: It now should contain all the information that You asked for

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible fixes is to add the JavaFX 11 library:

> Properties -> Libraries -> Run -> Modulepath